# Azure Table Storage vs Azure Document DB - performance comparison?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

All other things being equal (regarding feature requirements, data requirements, etc), which is faster in the following functions:

- Inserts
- Updates
- Reads
- Deletes

Please, I'm looking for a straight comparison of these raw functions given a scenario where either could be used equally effectively in terms of feature requirements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges, and there is no right answer to scenarios which you should choose one vs the other. But objectively, there are some discrete differences:

- Table storage supports up to 2,000 transactions / sec, per partition (dictated by your chosen partition key), and 20,000 transactions / sec for an entire storage account. The number of transactions is not guaranteed, and varies based on entity size
- DocumentDB, while not providing "transactions" per second, provides a guaranteed level of "Request Units" per second. And by measuring your various queries, you can then scale your database to provide an equivalent number of transactions per second that your app requires. DocumentDB, by allowing you to adjust RU for a given collection, effectively lets you scale to a larger transaction rate than possible with Table Storage (you can certainly utilize multiple storage accounts to raise your effective table storage transaction rate). DocumentDB offers up to 10K RU/sec per collection (standard collection) or 250K RU/sec (partitioned collection), and the limits may be raised as needed, per support.
- Table Storage supports Entity Group Transactions, allowing for operations of up to 100 entities (and up to 4MB payload) to be batched into a single atomic transaction. Transactions are bound to a single partition.
- DocumentDB allows for transactions to occur within the bounds of a collection. If multiple database operations are performed within a stored procedure, those operations succeed or fail atomically.
- Table Storage is a key/value store, and lookups on partition key + row key yield very efficient point-lookups. Once you start examining properties other than PK/RK, you will enter the space of partition scan or table scan.
- DocumentDB is a document store, and you may index any/all properties within a document.
- Table Storage scales to 500TB per account.
- DocumentDB scales to 250GB per collection, more if you request additional storage (e.g. 500TB).
- Table Storage provides security via storage access key. There's a master storage account key, as well as the ability to generate Shared Access Signatures to provide specific access rights to specific tables.
- DocumentDB has both read/write and read-only admin keys, along with user-level access to collections/documents
- Table Storage and DocumentDB have very different pricing models (where Table Storage is simply a per-GB-per-month cost, along with a nominal cost for transactions). But back to my point of apples vs oranges: DocumentDB is a *database engine* - query language, server-side procedures, triggers, indexes, etc.

I'm sure there are some objective comparisons that I missed, but that should give you a good starting point for making your decision to use one, the other, or both. And how you choose to apply each of these to your apps is really up to you, and what your priorities are (Scale? Queries? Cost? etc...).

Comment: David, thanks for this great answer. That pretty much tells me what I need to know and gives me a good launch point for discovering more if I need it. I know I'm comparing apples and oranges, that's why I said "all other things being equal". :-)